# Using prepare for Segue with global variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass information from 1 view controller to another. But, when I execute this code, NSLog shows the output null. I cant use prepare for segue because I am using the popViewControllerAnimated method. Is there any way I can use a global variable without the use of prepare for segue?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    aVariables = [GlobalVariables variables];

}

- (IBAction)adSwitchPressed:(id)sender {
if (adSwitch.isOn) {
    adString = @"ON";
}
if (!adSwitch.isOn) {
    adString = @"OFF";
    }
}

- (IBAction)tieSwitchPressed:(id)sender {
    if (tieSwitch.isOn) {
        tieString = @"ON";
    }
    if (!tieSwitch.isOn) {
        tieString = @"ON";
    }
    aVariables.gTieString2 = tieString;
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
    aVariables.gAdString = adString;
    aVariables.gTieString2 = tieString;
    NSLog(@"%@", aVariables.gAdString);
}

#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

}
```

Comment: There's nothing new in the subject you propose.  If you run a search for '[objective-c] pass values,' you'll get 4,700 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by El Tomato, its pretty standard stuff. I am answering this to guide you in right direction:

> Is there any way I can use a global variable without the use of
>   prepare for segue?

**Answer - Yes. Using delegate.** Like this:

**Step 1:** Define a model `GlobalVariables` like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gAdString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gTieString2;

@end
```

**Step 2:** Work out your `ViewController 2` like this:

**ViewController 2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)detailsSaved:(GlobalVariables *)iGlobalVariables;

@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id <ViewController2Delegate>)iDelegate;

@end
```

**ViewController 2.m**

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) GlobalVariables *globalVariables;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;

@end

@implementation ViewController2


- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id <ViewController2Delegate>)iDelegate {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.delegate = iDelegate;
        self.globalVariables = [[GlobalVariables alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}


- (IBAction)adSwitchPressed:(id)sender {
    if (adSwitch.isOn) {
        self.globalVariables.gAdString = @"ON";
    }
    if (!adSwitch.isOn) {
        self.globalVariables.gAdString = @"OFF";
    }
}

- (IBAction)tieSwitchPressed:(id)sender {
    if (tieSwitch.isOn) {
        self.globalVariables.gTieString2 = @"ON";
    }

    if (!tieSwitch.isOn) {
        self.globalVariables.gTieString2 = @"ON";
    }
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(detailsSaved:)]) {
        [self.delegate detailsSaved:self.globalVariables];
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

**Step 3:** Finally this is how your `ViewController 1` should look like:

**ViewController1.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <ViewController2Delegate>

@end
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

@implementation ViewController1

- (void)presentViewController2 {
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}


- (void)detailsSaved:(GlobalVariables *)iGlobalVariables {
    // Use global variables here
}

@end
```

**PS: This is the skeleton of how it should look like. You need to implement other view controller methods.**